# Google Sheet Script - onChange

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, onchange

Please help with Google onChange function Sheet Script. 
I only want to log onChange for one sheet "Attendance" the change on this sheet is then logged in "Sheet5"
When there is a change in "Attendance" column C, then copy the value of column B into "Sheet5" and add the current date and time. Here is some code I tried, but do not know how to change it.

```
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {

   ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange')
    .forSpreadsheet('ID to go here')
   .onChange()
   .create();

    }

function onChange(e) {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet5");
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,4).setValues([
    [e.changeType,
      e.source.getSheetName(),
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValue(),
     new Date()]
    ]);
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so].  First you have to understand the code you included in the question. If you didn't yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/trigggers, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events then come back and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Attendance' && e.range.columnStart==3 && e.range.rowStart>'Your header row') {
    e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet5").appendRow([e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue(),new Date()]);
  }
}
```

[onedit event obj](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Hi Cooper, that you for your response. The onEdit works perfectly, but I neglected to state in my original question, apologeis for this, that I need to use the onChange function as 3rd party accessing sheets will only work with onChange function. I tried changing the script from onEdit to onChange without luck.

Comment: Try using installable trigger.

Comment: Thx Cooper, yes I have a trigger "ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange')" installed and tested that is trigger the onChange funstion, but it seems that the onEdit script you suggested does nto work for onChange.

Comment: No of course not but I’m suggesting that you try an installable onEdit trigger. The on change event objects and the on edit event objects or entirely different. You should go read about the events objects in the documentation you’ll see they’re entirely different

Comment: Hi Cooper, after a lot of reading, the installable trigger works now and the rows, which is changed is copied to "Sheet5". I still have 1 problem that I am struggling with, it seems that the copy loops twice or sometimes 3 times. When I make a change on a record in “Attendance” it gets copy more than 1 to “Sheet5” Here is the current code